# Aptana Studio 3 takes 2 minutes to start up

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I've recently installed Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.1.3.201205292243 on a Win7 Enterprise 32bit machine with 4gb RAM.

I've uninstalled and re-installed it once (total two times installing) and yet shortly after I’ve set up my workspace for the first time, it starts to take around 2 minutes to start up from the time I see the splash screen until the perspective is loaded.
I’ve been able to trim down this crazy start up time by closing all files and deleting all project (just as a test), but it still takes about 30 seconds to load up.

Obviously, having no projects established is not an option but even if it was, a 30 second startup time is still way too long and not normal for this software based on my past experience.

I’ve used Aptana on other Windows 7 machines (both 32 and 64 bit) and never come across such an issue.  How can I troubleshoot this problem to find out what’s causing these long start up times and fix it?

max7

Answer (score 1):

Aptana has always taken an age to load. It was the reason I stopped using it. You could use Eclipse with the Aptana plugin which was faster for me but much uglier.

Comment: how odd because as I mentioned, this is the first time I've run into such a horrendous load time.  I have it running on two machines at home and no such problem there.

I was considering doing as you say (i.e. Eclipse w/Aptana plugin).  Should I go this route, I would use the Eclipse for Javascript Development but one thing I've never been clear about is, which package do I download: Helios, Ganymede, Indigo, etc?  What's the differences between them?

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late into this.

Edit  Aptanastudio.ini file in Aptana studio root folder to something like this

> -vmargs
>
> -Xmx1024M
>
> -Xms512M
>
> -Xverify:none
>
> -XX:+UseParallelGC
>
> -XX:+AggressiveOpts
>
> -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
>
> -XX:CompileThreshold=100
>
> -Djava.awt.headless=true
>
> -Djava.awt.nativeDoubleBuffering=true

[source](http://www.katasonov.com/2009/03/aptana-studio-optimization/)

Comment: This brought my 10+ minute first-start-time down to 2 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

I just learned how to disable git attachment in Aptana.  My workbench loads up in less than 10 seconds now (rather than the ~30 it was taking).

I clicked the down arrow by the gears by the project explorer panel, and I found an option that included the word "detach".  In my case this helps because I'm not using git on the machine that I'm working on the project from.

Comment: I see the gears icon only in App Explorer ... is that what you meant to say?  Regardless, there is no detach option available there.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this sort of thing is due to not having enough available memory. Your 32-bit Windows won't be able to use all of the 4 GB, and the memory available for aptana will depend on what else is running, including background process you didn't start yourself.

Right-click on your taskbar (bottom of screen), select "Task Manager", and look at the "commit charge" display on the window's status bar. If the first number is more than about 3G or 3000M I'd say you've got memory issues. Disclaimer: I'm not a Windows expert, YMMV.